# Ошибка "unresolved import" в visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

При импортировании каких-либо модулей VS Code выдает ошибку "unresolved import"

json.settings:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.analysis.logLevel": "Trace",
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python.exe",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "[python]": {

    },
    "python.jediEnabled": false
}
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы VS Code стал "видеть" модули?

Comment: `pip install <модуль>`?

Comment: Ошибка возникает абсолютно со всеми модулями, даже со стандартными

Comment: Может в `pythonPath` надо ещё диск указывать для полноты?

Answer (score 3):

У меня такая ошибка стала возникать после обновления VSCode где-то в начале этого года в том случае, если если питоновский код находится во вложенном каталоге.

Вот структура каталога проекта:

```
my_project
|--.vscode/
   |--settings.json
|--dir1/
|--dir2/
|--py_dir/
   |--file1.py
   |--file1.py
```

Если открыть в VSCode каталог `my_project` то проблема с импортом есть. Если открыть в VSCode каталог `py_dir` то проблемы с импортом нет.

Решается созданием в `my_project` файла `.env` со следующим содержимым:

```
PYTHONPATH=py_dir
```

`py_dir` - это путь к каталогу с кодом относительно каталога проекта.

И добавлением в настройки рабочего пространства (файл `.vscode/settings.json`) строки

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
```

В итоге должно получится так:

```
my_project
|--.env
|--.vscode/
   |--settings.json
|--dir1/
|--dir2/
|--py_dir/
   |--file1.py
   |--file1.py
```

После этого проблема импорта исчезла.

Отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55130141/8785369